# On boot, Ubuntu 13.04 reaches 89º C and shutdown

Tags: boot, 13.04, overheating, acpi

After install Ubuntu 13.04 my notebook, an inspiron 15R n5010, reaches 89ºC and shutdown. I tried to boot on recovery mode and before shutdown seems to say that "ACPI" gave the order. Somebody knows how to fix it? Or at least remember how to turn off the acpi mode. I did it once because of problems on the os but i cant remember how.

Comment: Is the CPU fan working? I do suggest cleaning out the dust bunnies

Answer (score 2):

You can turn off the ACPI through your BIOS. 
Try Re-booting and Hit F2 at dell logo.

Answer (score 0):

Yep.  Answer 1 is correct.  You may also want to remove and replace your notebook's CPU if you have the technical expertise to do so. The thermal paste Dell used on inspiron notebooks gets old after some time.  Removing the CPU, cleaning the past off of it and the heatsink and applying a better thermal paste (like Artic Silver) then reinstalling the CPU and heatsink could really bring your temps down.  Any compatible OS should run well on your notebook.  The overheating problem is a hardware issue, not software.  ACPI does have it's problems, but it saved you burning out your CPU by shutting it down.  Think about it.